# ALB ingress controller path based routing

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer

I have deployed ALB ingress controller with path based routing, after deploying application-ingress.yaml file defined paths were getting created in AWS console as we expected and also target groups also healthy.

But its working only /*, remaining paths (/app1, /app2) are not working getting error 404. please find the below ingress yaml file.

```
Let's say when I'm trying to access /app1 page https://my-domain-name/app1 getting error HTTP ERROR 404

Same way /app2 page https://my-domain-name/app2 getting error HTTP ERROR 404

And last one is /app3 page https://my-domain-name/app3 page is working as we expected
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-modulus-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}, {"HTTP":80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:249889768:certificate/267887899-1569-4b78-c557-12678906533
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-01234567, subnet-7654321
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-0667f8a234579865
spec:
  rules:
     - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app1
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app1-service
                port:
                  number: 30002
          - path: /app2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app2-service
                port:
                  number: 3030
           - path: /*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app3-service
                port:
                  number: 443
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove wildcard * and then check it will start working

Comment: It is working for me after removing *

Comment: I have the same issue, how do you make it work? By removing wildcard star? I tried this but it seems ALB is not supporting pathType: Prefix very well

Comment: I just removed '*' then it is working for me.